# Verify call to static method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I want to **verify** that a `public static void` method has been **called**.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ConsoleLog.class})
public class AdContentDataUnitTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ConsoleLog.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void adContentData_sendTrackingEvent_noUrl() throws Exception {
        mAdContentData = spy(mAdContentData);

        // PowerMockito.doNothing().when(ConsoleLog.class);

        verifyStatic();
        mAdContentData.sendTrackingEvent("event1");
        //verifyStatic();
    }
}
```

`sendTrackingEvent` will be invoked, and the `ConsoleLog.v(String, String)` will be called. I can see in debug that the static method is called, but the following log appear and the test fail:

```
Wanted but not invoked com.example.logger.ConsoleLog.v(
    "AdContentData",
    "sendTrackingEvent: event event1 does not exist."
);
```

I've tried to add the `verifyStatic` after but same log, and if I remove the first verify, nothing is checked. If I mock the whole ConsoleLog class the error `Unfinished stubbing detected here: [...] PowerMockitoCore.doAnswer` appear.

**Does anyone know how to do it properly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do anyone know how to do it properly?

Yes. Don't do it at all.

Let's say you have a class that calls a static method like this:

```
class Person {
    private final int id;

    Person() {
        id = IdGenerator.gen();
    }
}
```

Extract the static call to a non-static method:

```
class Person {
    private final int id;

    Person() {
        id = generateId();
    }

    protected int generateId() {
        return IdGenerator.gen();
    }
}
```

Now you can write a test, overriding the extracted method:

```
    final int id = 1;
    Person person = new Person() {
        @Override
        protected int generateId() {
            return id;
        }
    };

    // test with person, knowing we control id
```

But the ideal solution is actually to refactor the code under test to not use such static calls at all, but dependency injection.

Comment: this is a solution but it reduce the performance as we need to call one method more (I'm on Android and perf matters)

Comment: The compiler may very well inline such method calls. Are you sure it makes a significant perf difference? Have you measured it? I forgot to mention the ideal solution is to refactor to code under test to not use static calls but use dependency injection

Comment: well, the `ConsoleLog` is a wrap class of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: I see this is on Android, so maybe you cannot inject it. So you can ignore my suggestion about dependency injection. But the "extract and override" technique suggestion still stands. A single indirection is unlikely to make a difference in terms of perf, and it's reasonable to *presume innocent until proven guilty* (benchmark measurements showing a non-negligible difference)